# cannot access grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString())

Tags: grails, controller, app-config

I tried  from a controller to use grailsApplication information to create some folder, however,

what I got from the following line of code is "false" - my grails application runs well, though....

```
File(grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString()).mkdirs()
```

could some one help, please?

thanks.

**edit**: thank you leebutts for your quick answer.  my embarassment is that I always get ${grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString()} as null. But my grails application works very well.....please excuse me if this question seems too naive for the experienced grails experts because i'm really new to the wonderful technology....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that directory already exist?

mkdirs() returns true only if it creates the directory.

cheers

Lee

Comment: thank you for your answer.  and you are right.  however, even grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString()) is [], which means that mkdirs() gets false because the former is null....

Comment: Can you post your config.groovy where you set the location?